# LNK1104: cannot open file 'Debug\*.obj'

Tags: visual-studio, linker, masm

I'm creating a simple assembly program in visual studio with MASM. It seemed to be compiling fine and such, until I modified the source and attempted to re-build the project. This time, I get the following

```
All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
NuGet package restore finished.
1>------ Build started: Project: Add, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Assembling Add.asm...
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Debug\Add.obj'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Object File Name in Microsoft Macro Assembler is left as default, `$(IntDir)%(FileName).obj`. The full command line is as follows `ml.exe /c /nologo /EP /Zi /Fo"Debug\%(FileName).obj" /Fl"Add.lst" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Ta`. This worked for the original build, but it complains there's no object file even though /Fo clearly specifies it.

Comment: is the `.obj` file in the _Debug_ folder?

Comment: No. It was never generated even after right clicking Add.asm and selecting compile.

Comment: So did you get `ml` to assemble your file? What's the purpose of the last flag (`/Ta`) ?

Comment: Yes it compiled successfully. I was able to even create a new project entirely to verify this, where I don't get the error stated in the OP, but I do run into a runtime error. About `/Ta`, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0ksfwcf.aspx states `Assembles source file whose name does not end with the .asm extension.`

Comment: I know what `/Ta` does, I asked because of the 4th line in the output included in the question: `1>  Assembling Add.asm...`.

Comment: It seems to actually work now with this new project solution after modifying its source

Comment: That's what really matters at the end.